# Not able to view the last cells in UITableView after activating UISearchbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios-simulator, uisearchbar

here's my code for initializing my search bar

```
    -(IBAction)goToSearch:(id)sender {
    [self initSearchBar];
}

- (void)initSearchBar {
    self.tableView.showsInfiniteScrolling = NO;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
    _searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
    _searchBar.delegate = self;
    _searchBar.placeholder = @"Search";
    _searchBar.showsBookmarkButton = NO;
    [_searchBar sizeToFit];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = _searchBar;
    [_searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
    [_searchBar.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    self.navigationItem.titleView.alpha = 0.0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                     animations:^{
                         self.navigationItem.titleView.alpha = 1.0;
                     }];
}
```

Here's the code for when the cancel button is clicked

```
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    isSearching = NO;
    self.tableView.showsInfiniteScrolling = YES;
    [self reloadDatawithAnimation];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView;
    self.navigationItem.titleView.alpha = 0.0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                     animations:^{
                         self.navigationItem.titleView.alpha = 1.0;
                     }];
    UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButton =
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch
                                                  target:self
                                                  action:@selector(goToSearch:)];
    [_searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
    [_searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton;
}
```

After tapping the search icon which calls `goToSearch`, which calls `initSearchBar` then either searching and clicking cancel, or just clicking cancel make the `tableview` stop with about 4 cells to go.

Now the strange part is that this problem is not present in the simulator, while it does appear on the actual phone!

I've tried reordering and removing just about every single line and it seems that whenever  the search bar is put in as the titleView the problem is caused.

EDIT: 
So If I take out `self.tableView.showsInfiniteScrolling = NO;` from `initSearchBar` it seems to solve the problem, however I need to turn that off during searching.

EDIT EDIT: Checked `tableview` size and offsets. They all remain constant through both functions

On top of that, if I replace the code in `initSearchBar` with the code below, the problem does not persist. I'm really confused now

```
    self.tableView.showsInfiniteScrolling = NO;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    self.tableView.showsInfiniteScrolling = YES;
```

Any ideas?

I am also using `SVPullToRefresh`, but I am not sure if that is related.

Comment: use scrollEnabled property, hope it will work

Comment: Can you explain a little more?

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout ?

Comment: Seems to me like an auto layout problem no?

Comment: When you say it works fine on simulator but not on device, are you sure that this is not related to a version of iOS (i.e. simulator in 8.1 and device in 8.0)

Comment: device is on 8.1 and is up to date, but let me double check the versions.

And I did just use a UITableViewController, and don't assign dimensions to the table view so I am using auto layout

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to tackle the autolayout issue,  does this mean I need to not use it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that self.tableView.showsInfiniteScrolling does not come from the standard frameworks, I would really like to know what framework or library you are using.

That said, I found [this](http://jslim.net/blog/2014/04/01/infinite-scroll-using-on-uitableview/) page showing an exemple of it's use but in a UIScrollView. An interesting comment before a line made me think of your situation:

> // once refresh, allow the infinite scroll again
>
> weakSelf.tableView.showsInfiniteScrolling = YES;

I believe that your above works because you enable the infinite scrolling after you reload the table.

```
self.tableView.showsInfiniteScrolling = NO;
[self.tableView reloadData];
self.tableView.showsInfiniteScrolling = YES;
```

Try commenting out your first line in there to see if it works!

Comment: SVPullToRefresh is what I am using. It's in the bottom line of the original post :)

Comment: And this does not seem to help

Comment: Also, notice that it seems to work fine in the simulator, while the issue only persists on an actual device